# How to merge 2 arrays of object with extra matching

Tags: javascript, arrays

I actually don't know what this is called, hence the "extra matching" in the title

I have 2 arrays of objects

`[{player_1: 'adeshina'}, {player_1: 'MindReaper'}]`

and

`[{player_2: 'thinkerbull'}, {player_2: 'AfroGamer'}]`

How can I merge it to become `{player_1: 'adeshina', player_2: 'thinkerbull'}, {player_1: 'MindReaper', player_2: 'AfroGamer'}` ?

Comment: Pleas post the code that you have worked with, so that we can help where you are blocked.

Comment: A simple loop can solve your problem, just try first and add the code that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually called "zipping". You wanna zip two arrays.

It can be done using `map`:

```
var a = [{player_1: 'adeshina'}, {player_1: 'MindReaper'}]
var b = [{player_2: 'thinkerbull'}, {player_2: 'AfroGamer'}]


var c = a.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, b[i]];
});

console.log(c)
```

A shorter version would be:

```
c = a.map((e, i) =>[e, b[i]]);
```

Comment: Please avoid answering to questions where the user have not even attempted anything or have not mentioed what difficulty he is facing with.

Comment: @Nitheesh he asked how it is called and how it should be done, please explain your comment

Comment: @bArmageddon Thanks
I now understnad

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to loop through the arrays and merge the objects,

like this:

```
const arrayOne = [{player_1: 'adeshina'}, {player_1: 'MindReaper'}]
const arrayTwo = [{player_2: 'thinkerbull'}, {player_2: 'AfroGamer'}]

const newArray = arrayOne.map( (e, index) => ({...e, ...arrayTwo[index]}));
```

Comment: Please avoid answering to questions where the user have not even attempted anything or have not mentioed what difficulty he is facing with.